# getting error while fetch "hindi" results from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to fetch "hindi" (utf-8) results from MySQL database using php.

I have written the following code..

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if(!connection)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET name=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');

mysql_select_db('data',$connection);
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$cmd = "select * from question";
$result = mysql_query($cmd);

$myArray = array();

while($row =$result->fetch_object()){
$tempArray = $row;
array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

But I am not getting the expected results. I want to print Utf-8(Hindi) data.

if I use the following code to print individual row then

```
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo ($myrow[0]);
echo ($myrow[1]);
echo ($myrow[2]);
}
```

It works fine and prints the utf-8(Hindi) data.

Please help me what I am missing or is there anything wrong implemented....

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: If you want to use the most upto date features of mysql and PHP why are you using `mysql_*`? Additionally `I am not getting the expected results` tells us nothing of what you are getting nor what is expected... are you getting errors?

Comment: What's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE question`?

Comment: And whilst we're here what's the output of `var_dump(mysql_client_encoding($connection));` ? Both of those should have the charset as utf8 if they aren't that might be your problem :)

Comment: I am getting "fatal error call to member function on non-object" at line  while($row =$result->fetch_object())

Comment: And when using this while($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo ($myrow[0]);
echo ($myrow[1]);
echo ($myrow[2]);
} it is printing the results correctly. but while trying to convert it in array it is not working

Comment: You executed the query with `mysql` driver and trying to retrieve the result in `mysqli` driver.

Comment: Can you tell me how to retrieve the result using MySQL driver in json_encoded array.

Comment: Do you want to store the result as JSON array using `json_encode`?

Comment: yes i want to store the result as JSON array using json_encode

Comment: The output of var_dump(mysql_client_encoding($connection)); is string 'latin1' (length=6)

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_query('SET name=utf8');

Should be `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');`.  The other SETs are not needed.

Also, don't use the deprecated mysql_* interface, rewrite to use mysqli_* (or PDO).

By Hindi, do you mean DEVANAGARI, such as `हिन्दी` ?
The utf8 hex for that is: `E0A4B9 E0A4BF E0A4A8 E0A58D E0A4A6 E0A580`
If you see something like `à¤¹à¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¦à¥€`, you have "Mojibake".

> not getting the expected results

What are you getting?

`json_encode` -- should include a second argument of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to avoid getting the "html entities".

To see hex in PHP,

```
$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
echo implode('', $hex);
```

`latin1` will not suffice; you need `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

I realize this is not a full or coherent answer, but it presents several action items for the OP to get closer to the solution.